# CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka **0.9.0.1 broker** and **0.9.0.1 consumer client**. My consumer instances are consuming records with a processing time less than 1 second. And other main configs are

```
enable.auto.commit=false
session.timeout.ms=30000
heartbeat.interval.ms=25000
```

I am committing offset after processing.
I am getting the exception

> Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group
>   kafka_to_s3
>
> ERROR com.bsb.hike.analytics.consumer.Consumer - unable to commit
>   retryCount=2 org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException:
>   Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance

once or twice in an hour. Consuming approx 6 billion events a day. It seems like offsets are stored in only one partition of the topic "__consumer_offsets". It increase the load on the particular broker also.

Anybody have clue about these problems ?

Answer (score 8):

Kafka triggers a rebalance if it doesn't receive at least one heartbeat within session time out. If the rebalance is triggered, the commit will fail. That is expected. So the question is why has the heartbeat not happened? There might be a couple of reasons for that.

1. First thing is that you are doing a manual commit. Starting 0.9, heartbeat doesn't happen in a separate thread. The consumer runs on a single thread which handles commit, heartbeat and polling. So the heartbeat happens when you do a consumer.poll() or consumer.commit(). So if your processing time is exceeding the session time out, that might cause the heartbeat to fail.
2. There is a known issue in kafka 0.9 consumer which might cause the problem you are facing.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3627

In either case, downgrading your consumer to 0.8 will solve the problem.

Edit: You can try increasing the session time out to as high as 5 min and see if it works.

**Regarding kafka configs**

Kafka server expects that it receives at least one heartbeat within the session time out. So the consumer tries to do a heartbeat at most (session time out/heartbeat times). Some heartbeats might be missed. So your heartbeat time should not be more than 1/3 of the session time out. (You can refer to the docs)